# Why won't Dynamics AX integration framework accept namespace prefixes on xsi:type attributes and how do I make it?

Tags: xml, axapta

I'm writing an integration with Dynamics AX, calling an inbound web service to create a global address book entry.

The create request contains an entity body

`<DirPartyTable xsi:type="ns0:Axd_DirPartyTable_DirOrganization">`

The web service rejects this complaining about this entity type name, with the error message:

> Error - Invalid instance type name
>   'ns0:AxdEntity_DirPartyTable_DirOrganization'.

All the types and names are as generated from the service WSDL. For other integrations, manipulating the request with string substitution to remove this namespace prefix makes the request accepted.

Why won't AX allow this perfectly valid attribute and what configuration do I have to do to make it so?

The background of this question is that I am developing the outside integration and know next to nothing about AX - but I am unlikely to get the time of anyone who does know the product unless I can prove that there is a simple resolution to the problem rather than hacking it at my end.

Comment: Can you please provide a full sample request and not just one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the reason was that the semicolon-separated list of values provided as the `Roles` element content included a value that wasn't recognised. This is apparently matched to a drop-down list that has certain preconfigured values. Of course the error message gives no indication that this is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not encountered this exact scenario myself, having written several integrations for AX in the past what immediately jumps out at me is that you are trying to insert data into a table that is based on table inheritance.

This means the table doesn't actually exist in SQL, it's just an abstraction added by AX/X++ for easier development. DirPartyTable is the "real" table in SQL, DirOrganization is the inherited abstraction in AX that adds more fields to the parent DirPartyTable table. DirPerson is another table that inherits from DirPartyTable. The thing is, neither DirOrganization nor DirPerson exist in SQL, both are actually different children of the DirPartyTable adding X++ logic and extra fields to their respective "tables". This might end up causing issues with entities, as I know table inheritance has caused me some grief in the past.

If you have an AX developer resource I would ask him/her to investigate this line of thought and see if the table inheritance is causing you issues.

As far as what configuration would be needed to make it valid, I don't have that answer for you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - it is indeed an inheritance-based scenario; the `xsi:type` annotation is added automatically indicating that the DirPartyTable is created using one of its XML extensions - these are as-defined in the web service schemas. I would call it a bug if AX doesn't accept data structures which it defines itself. We do have a workaround that manipulates the request XML in a number of ways before sending, but it's taking a disproportionate amount of work to modify the type annotation where there is nothing wrong with it and it should be accepted.

Comment: Agreed, I would call it a bug as well... and it would appear that you're not the only one to have this problem as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404269/how-do-i-disable-namespace-aliasing-in-php-soap-client
Maybe it is worthwhile to open a support case if the issue persists as there is no answer on that question yet either.